# XSLT 1.0 loop elements after grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I need your help with a XSLT 1.0 problem.

Original XML:

```
    <businessevent>
       <catalog>
          <de name="16R">FIN</de>
          <ds name="35B">
             <de name="instrument_identification">ISIN AT0000A0U3T4</de>
             <de name="instrument_type">ISIN</de>
             <de name="instrument_code">AT0000A0U3T4</de>
             <de name="instrument_code_code">AT0000A0U3T4</de>
             <de name="instrument_code_umi_id">ATG2022113.4</de>
             <de name="instrument_code_code">AT0000A0U3T4</de>
             <de name="instrument_code_umi_id">ATG2022113.4_SG</de>
          </ds>
          <de name="16R">FIA</de>
          <de name="12A">:CLAS/ISIT/GOVT</de>
          <ds name="98A">
             <de name="date_type">MATU</de>
             <de name="date">20051122</de>
          </ds>
          <ds name="98A">
             <de name="date_type">ISSU</de>
             <de name="date">20060126</de>
          </ds>
          <de name="92A">:INTR//3,4</de>
          <de name="16S">FIA</de>
          <de name="90A">:MRKT//PRCT/114,16</de>
          <ds name="93B">
             <de name="amount_type">AGGR</de>
             <de name="unit_type">FAMT</de>
             <de name="amount">100</de>
          </ds>
          <ds name="93B">
             <de name="amount_type">AVAI</de>
             <de name="unit_type">FAMT</de>
             <de name="amount">100</de>
          </ds>
          <ds name="93B">
             <de name="amount_type">NAVL</de>
             <de name="unit_type">FAMT</de>
             <de name="amount">0</de>
          </ds>
          <de name="16R">SUBBAL</de>
          <ds name="93B">
             <de name="amount_type">AGGR</de>
             <de name="unit_type">FAMT</de>
             <de name="amount">100</de>
          </ds>
          <de name="16S">SUBBAL</de>
          <de name="19A">:HOLD//EUR6000,</de>
          <de name="16S">FIN</de>


          <de name="16R">FIN</de>
          <ds name="35B">
             <de name="instrument_identification">ISIN AT0000A0VRF9</de>
             <de name="instrument_type">ISIN</de>
             <de name="instrument_code">AT0000A0VRF9</de>
             <de name="instrument_code_code">AT0000A0VRF9</de>
             <de name="instrument_code_umi_id">ATG2019061.95</de>
          </ds>
          <de name="16R">FIA</de>
          <de name="12A">:CLAS/ISIT/GOVT</de>
          <ds name="98A">
             <de name="date_type">MATU</de>
             <de name="date">20120618</de>
          </ds>
          <ds name="98A">
             <de name="date_type">ISSU</de>
             <de name="date">20110703</de>
          </ds>
          <de name="92A">:INTR//1,95</de>
          <de name="16S">FIA</de>
          <de name="90A">:MRKT//PRCT/100,47</de>
          <ds name="93B">
             <de name="amount_type">AGGR</de>
             <de name="unit_type">FAMT</de>
             <de name="amount">200</de>
          </ds>
          <ds name="93B">
             <de name="amount_type">AVAI</de>
             <de name="unit_type">FAMT</de>
             <de name="amount">200</de>
          </ds>
          <ds name="93B">
             <de name="amount_type">NAVL</de>
             <de name="unit_type">FAMT</de>
             <de name="amount">0</de>
          </ds>
          <de name="16R">SUBBAL</de>
          <ds name="93B">
             <de name="amount_type">AGGR</de>
             <de name="unit_type">FAMT</de>
             <de name="amount">200</de>
          </ds>
          <de name="16S">SUBBAL</de>
          <de name="19A">:HOLD//EUR1000,</de>
          <de name="16S">FIN</de>
       </catalog>
    </businessevent>
```

As you can see it is a flat XML with a weird structure and I can only use XSLT 1.0 to manipulate it. The sub-structure repeats initiating with

```
    <de name="16R">FIN</de>
```

and ends with

```
    <de name="16S">FIN</de>
```

For each of this repeating structure I need to get some of the info and only the first occurrence of 93B with amount_type = AGGR. In the first "group" it repeats and its giving me problems.

Expected result:

```
    <businessevent>
       <catalog>
            <ds>
                <de name="instrument_identification">ISIN AT0000A0U3T4</de>
                <de name="instrument_type">ISIN</de>
                <de name="instrument_code">AT0000A0U3T4</de>
                <de name="amount">100</de>
            </ds>
        </catalog>
    </businessevent>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual output you expect, as getting information is one thing, but actually doing something with it is another. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC, please look into the updated question

Comment: Did you mean to change the input XML too, because the XSLT provided will no longer work on that structure? (You would need to amend to use a "group-ending-with" approach). Thanks

Comment: Yes, because after some testing I found out the original XML would not solve my real issue. Sorry for that Tim :(

Comment: Tim, please don't spend time trying to solve this example. I will edit my question with the real problem so you can aid me better. Give me a few minutes...

Comment: Hello again Tim. Please look into my new post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your previous question, you can still do a form of "group-starting-with" by using the following key:

```
<xsl:key name="start" match="catalog/*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::de[@name='16R'][. = 'FIN'][1])" />
```

To get the first three elements you want, in "35B", you would then do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('start', generate-id())[self::ds[@name='35B']]" mode="ds-35B" />
```

And do get the first "93B" element, with amount_type of "AGGR" you could do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('start', generate-id())[self::ds[@name='93B'][de[@name='amount_type']='AGGR']][1]" mode="ds-93B" />
```

Try it this way...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="start" match="catalog/*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::de[@name='16R'][. = 'FIN'][1])" />

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="de[@name='16R'][. = 'FIN']">
        <group>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('start', generate-id())[self::ds[@name='35B']]" mode="ds-35B" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('start', generate-id())[self::ds[@name='93B'][de[@name='amount_type']='AGGR']][1]" mode="ds-93B" />
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ds" mode="ds-35B">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="de[@name='instrument_identification' or @name='instrument_type' or @name='instrument_code']" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ds" mode="ds-93B">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="de[@name='amount']" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="businessevent">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|de[@name='16R' and . = 'FIN']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="de[@name='16R' and . = 'FIN']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ds[@name='35B'][1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ds[@name='35B']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="de[@name='instrument_identification']"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="de[@name='instrument_type']"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="de[@name='instrument_code']"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ds[de[@name='amount_type' and . = 'AGGR']][1]/de[@name='amount']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```